# Approximately what fraction of the galaxy's stars are in the bulge?

Tags: galaxy, mass

In the text of the question it is said to consider density uniformly

Comment: This seems to be a "homework" question: you say "in the text of the question...".  Just posting your homework online isn't much use to use or to anyone else.  If you can explain what you have done to answer this, and why you doubt your answer, then maybe [astronomy.se] can help.  The assumption that density is uniform would seem to be very far from the truth.